# Correlation between the count of combinations

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a `df`:

```
my_data = {'order_id': {('group_1', 'A'): 2,
  ('group_1', 'B'): 4,
  ('group_1', 'C'): 6,
  ('group_1', 'D'): 5,
  ('group_10', 'A'): 6,
  ('group_10', 'B'): 4,
  ('group_10', 'C'): 7,
  ('group_10', 'D'): 13,
  ('group_2', 'A'): 3,
  ('group_2', 'B'): 4,
  ('group_2', 'C'): 1,
  ('group_2', 'D'): 4,
  ('group_3', 'A'): 5,
  ('group_3', 'B'): 1,
  ('group_3', 'C'): 3,
  ('group_3', 'D'): 6,
  ('group_4', 'A'): 4,
  ('group_4', 'B'): 8,
  ('group_4', 'C'): 4,
  ('group_4', 'D'): 10,
  ('group_5', 'A'): 3,
  ('group_5', 'B'): 3,
  ('group_5', 'C'): 5,
  ('group_5', 'D'): 8,
  ('group_6', 'A'): 8,
  ('group_6', 'B'): 7,
  ('group_6', 'C'): 2,
  ('group_6', 'D'): 5,
  ('group_7', 'A'): 3,
  ('group_7', 'B'): 5,
  ('group_7', 'C'): 3,
  ('group_7', 'D'): 7,
  ('group_8', 'A'): 7,
  ('group_8', 'B'): 2,
  ('group_8', 'C'): 6,
  ('group_8', 'D'): 4,
  ('group_9', 'A'): 4,
  ('group_9', 'B'): 7,
  ('group_9', 'C'): 6,
  ('group_9', 'D'): 4}}
```

While using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` I lose the multiindex, not sure how I can preserve the multiindex hierarchy.

The `df.unstack()` looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to answer a question - *Is there a correlation between the type of customer group and the type of product bought?*

I ended up grouping the data by these two dimensions to get a count of how many each `customer_group` bought each `product_type`, the `df` is the result of that.

Now if I use:

`df.corr()` I get:

[image]

And the `product_type` is gone, and now I am thinking if `corr()` is not applicable in this type of question?

My desired result would be an answer how correlated are the order combinations of `product_type` and `customer_group`. And now taking a second look at the first `df`, maybe I can say that the combination that had the most sales `group_10` & `D` are the most correlated?

Comment: you can get a correlation between two _vectors_ (i.e. between customer groups or order types), but not between two _scalars_ (e.g. group 10 and customer D)

Comment: As @Stef outlined, a statstical correlation can only be computed between vectors. What you have as a result of your `df.unstack()` is a count matrix that merely counts the number of occurences so, again, scalars as mentioned in the comment. So `df.corr()` does produce a result but not the one you seek!

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Can you suggest a statistical approach to this kind of question I am trying to answer - is there any pattern in groups and types in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the answer to your original question (see my comment above), but it's too long for a comment. Based on **relative** sales you can answer the following questions:

**Which product group is the most popular for each customer group?**

```
pd.Series(df.index[(df.to_numpy().T / df.sum(axis=1).to_numpy()).T.argmax(axis=0)], index=df.columns.get_level_values(1))
```

Answer:

```
A     group_8
B     group_2
C     group_1
D    group_10
```

**Which customer group buys the most of each product group?**

```
pd.Series(df.columns.get_level_values(1)[(df.to_numpy() / df.sum(axis=0).to_numpy()).argmax(axis=1)], index=df.index)
```

Answer:

```
group_1     C
group_10    D
group_2     B
group_3     A
group_4     B
group_5     D
group_6     A
group_7     B
group_8     A
group_9     B
```